# adding `name` and `description` box for `Cesium PolylineCollection`

Tags: javascript, opengl, opengl-3, cesiumjs

On the `cesium sandcastle` page @ https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Polyline.html&label=Geometries

[image]

You can see, when I click on the purple line I get a box(top right corner of the image) indicating `name` of the `Cesium` `[Polyline][2]` as `"Purple straight arrow at height"`. How can I add the same `name box` for the `[PolylineCollection][2]` (line no 5 in code below)?

Here is the code

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');



var lineCollection = new Cesium.PolylineCollection(); // line no 5
lineCollection.add({
        name : "Hi",
        description : "Hi description",
        positions : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights([-75, 53, 500000,
                                                               -125, 53, 500000]),
        width : 10,
        followSurface : false
    });
viewer.scene.primitives.add(lineCollection);



var purpleArrow = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Purple straight arrow at height',
    polyline : {
        positions : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights([-75, 43, 500000,
                                                               -125, 43, 500000]),
        width : 10,
        followSurface : false,
        material : new Cesium.PolylineArrowMaterialProperty(Cesium.Color.PURPLE)
    }
});


viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);
```

Comment: `Polyline` is added as `Cesium Viewer Entity` https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Entity.html?classFilter=Entity while `PolylineCollection` is added as `Cesium Scene Primitives` https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Primitive.html?classFilter=Polyline

Answer (score 2):

Names and descriptions are part of the higher-level "Entity" API in Cesium.  Down at the graphics primitive level, where `PolylineCollection` is, there is no such thing.

Do you need to be using the lower-level API?  Typically, users who want high-level functions like the green selection indicator, info boxes, names & descriptions, etc., should stick to Entities, not primitives.

That said, there's a way to detect when primitives are "picked" by the mouse, and look up some names and info, and command the info box to manually update.  All this logic is built-in to the Entity layer though, so you should think twice before re-implementing it in your own app.

Comment: thank you. Yes entities have the features but not the pimitives. My code is somehow depending on existing code and I can't choose Entity. What's the way to achieve the same in Primitives as you explained.